# Simple search in Django

Tags: django, search

I have a really simple blog application and I want to add a really simple search feature to it.

There are 3 key fields to my model.

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100) # the title
    intro = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True) # an extract
    content = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True) # full post
```

I don't need a Google. I don't want to search comments (which are held on Disqus anyway). I just want a date-ranked, keyword filtered set of posts.

Everything I find on Google for some form of "django" and "search" comes back with hideously complicated Haystack+backend solutions. I don't *need* all that. I don't want to eat up more resources on a low-usage feature (I used to have a search box before I ported to Django and it had perhaps 4 searches a month).

The reason I'm taking time to ask on here (rather than just writing a messy little script) is **this already exists in the admin**. You can set the columns to search on and then just search and it "just works".

Is there some way of getting a handle on the admin-provided search and pulling it into my user-facing app?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

If you want a really simple search you can use [`icontains`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#contains) lookup and [`Q` object](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects):

```
from django.db.models import Q
results = BlogPost.objects.filter(Q(title__icontains=your_search_query) | Q(intro__icontains=your_search_query) | Q(content__icontains=your_search_query))
```

You should also note that Haystack doesn't have to be "hideously complicated". You can set up haystack with Whoosh backend in less then 15 minutes.

**Update 2016:** In version 1.10 Django added [a full text search support](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/postgres/search/) (PostgreSQL only). An answer to the original question using the new module might look something like this:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.search import SearchVector

results = BlogPost.objects.annotate(
    search=SearchVector('title', 'intro', 'content'),
).filter(search=your_search_query)
```

The new full text search module contains a lot more features (for example sorting by relevancy), you can [read about them in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/postgres/search/).

Comment: I concur, Haystack+Whoosh is pretty easy to get going. Might as well go with google site search if even that's too much effort.

Comment: By complicated I didn't just mean the setup. It's miles more code than this one-liner. I know it *does* a lot more with a lot better performance but quick, dirty search is all I'm after at the moment. Thanks! @Stijn pulling in another search engine (I'd go with Bing because they have a proper server-side API still) will be my next port of call if dirty searching doesn't work out.

Comment: Thanks for this, very helpful. What if the search provides no results? How would we generate and add a new BlogPost() object?

Answer (score 6):

From the Django [source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/5211f48ae3cc0d87a260dbf5c3ab8bdae664c4b6/django/contrib/admin/views/main.py#L222-L242):

```
# Apply keyword searches.
def construct_search(field_name):
    if field_name.startswith('^'):
        return "%s__istartswith" % field_name[1:]
    elif field_name.startswith('='):
        return "%s__iexact" % field_name[1:]
    elif field_name.startswith('@'):
        return "%s__search" % field_name[1:]
    else:
        return "%s__icontains" % field_name

if self.search_fields and self.query:
    for bit in self.query.split():
        or_queries = [models.Q(**{construct_search(str(field_name)): bit}) for field_name in self.search_fields]
        qs = qs.filter(reduce(operator.or_, or_queries))
    for field_name in self.search_fields:
        if '__' in field_name:
            qs = qs.distinct()
            break
```

Clearly, it uses the database options to perform search. If nothing else, you should be able to reuse some of the code from it.

So says the documentation too: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.search_fields

The full text search, however, uses the MySQL index (only if you are using MySQL).

Answer (score 4):

You would use the __search operator. It's documented in the [Django QuerySet API Reference](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/models/querysets/#search). There's also [istartswith](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/models/querysets/#istartswith), which does a case-insensitive starts-with search.

Here's a working example (adapted from my own Django site):

```
def search(request):
    try:
        q = request.GET['q']
        posts = BlogPost.objects.filter(title__search=q) | \
                BlogPost.objects.filter(intro__search=q) | \
                BlogPost.objects.filter(content__search=q)
        return render_to_response('search/results.html', {'posts':posts, 'q':q})
    except KeyError:
        return render_to_response('search/results.html')
```

Note that __search is only available in MySQL and requires direct manipulation of the database to add the full-text index. See the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-boolean.html) for additional details.

Comment: The "__search" operator only works with certain backends and table types that support fulltext indexes.

Comment: Thanks, I've included this in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to work just like the admin, you could try my mini-lib [Django simple search](https://github.com/gregplaysguitar/django-simple-search). It's basically a port of the admin search functionality. Install it with pip:

```
pip install django-simple-search
```

and use it like:

```
from simple_search import search_filter
from .models import BlogPost

search_fields = ['^title', 'intro', 'content']
query = 'search term here'
posts = BlogPost.objects.filter(search_filter(search_fields, query))
```

I also wrote a blog post about it: https://gregbrown.co/projects/django-simple-search